# Creating a new folder, where the name of the folder is given by the user

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an application where users can create new folders and save data into it.
When the user clicks on "Add folder", an alert dialog box appears with a text field to take the name of the folder from the user.
This is my code

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.folder_dialog,null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Create New Folder")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    String value = input.getText().toString();
                    File ABC=new File("/Simply-File/Pdf",value);
                    if(!ABC.exists())
                    {
                        ABC.mkdir();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Folder Created!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            });


    return builder.create();
}
```

I've already created a parent directory, which looks like this

```
   private void writeExternalStorage()
{
    String state;
    state= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {

        File root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File Dir=new File(root.getAbsolutePath(),"/Simply-File/Pdf");
        if(!Dir.exists())
        {
            Dir.mkdirs();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SD card not detected!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and i have also requested permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

folder_dialog.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<EditText
    android:hint="Folder Name"
    android:id="@+id/create_folder"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @plaskoff i am not able to create a folder with the name specified by the user, the first code is about taking the name from the user and creating a new folder using that name.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @plaskoff nothing really. The alert dialog asks the Name for the folder, when I enter it and click ok, it does not create a new folder.

Comment: Could you also show `folder_dialog.xml` layout?

Comment: @plaskoff I've posted it above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `EditText`. You're creating a new `EditText` and assigning the text from it to `value` variable when user clicks OK on the dialog. This `value` will always be an empty string because this `EditText` is not the one displayed in the `Dialog`. You're inflating a view from a layout file and then setting that view in the `builder` and the `EditText` displayed in the `Dialog` will be the one that's declared in the XML file.

Since you have an `EditText` with `android:id="@+id/create_folder"` declared in your `folder_dialog.xml` layout file you should be getting that view by ID instead of creating a new `EditText` programatically.

This portion of the code:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
builder.setView(input);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.folder_dialog,null);
builder.setView(view) (...)
```

should be changed to this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
final EditText input = view.findViewById(R.id.create_folder);
builder.setView(view) (...)
```

Comment: is create_name the ID of the edit text that is in the folder_dialog.xml?

Comment: Yes, it should matching the one in the XML (create_folder), I corrected it.

Comment: sorry for replying late. I've tried what you suggested, also understood where I went wrong, but I'm still not able to create a new folder with the name specified by the user.

Comment: What version of Android are you trying to do this on?

Comment: API 21: Android 5.0